# error: expected ',' or '...' before 'data'

Tags: compiler-errors, arduino, atmega

I'm using Arduino software (1.6.5) - Windows 8.1.
I'm getting this error on line 10:

> sketch_jul11a:10: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'data'

As far as I can see, it's completely unjustified.
First 12 lines:

```
#include <VirtualWire.h>

String id = "CCU";
String sid = "";

boolean debug = true;

char *controller;

int RG_global_tx_indicator = 0; //ERROR ON THIS LINE
int RG_global_rx_indicator = 0;
```

All settings are default and there's no issue with the import.
The question is, what's going on here?

If anyone could shine some light, that'd be great.

Comment: Are you sure it's not VirtualWire.h fault? I just tried with Arduino IDE 1.6.5 and Windows 8.1 64bit and an empty sketch with all the initialization you wrote is fine. Try removing the library (and its references) and it should work.. By the way, on the website they wrote `This VirtualWire library has now been superceded by the RadioHead library`. Probably you should try to move to the new one..

Comment: You need to post more of your sketch. If I added definitions of setup and loop, your snippet compiles OK. Try to make a complete sketch that exhibits the error. Probably further down is a function that did not get a correct prototype generated.

Comment: I'm going to throw out a guess that you've inadvertently added an invisible non-ASCII character somewhere in your code. Try pasting your entire code into [an online tool](http://www.ubertoolz.com/demo/CleanUp.php) to clean it up and then paste back into your sketch.